# How is the pentaho community server installed on linux?

Tags: pentaho

Where can I find the pentaho community files, how is it installed, and how do I access the user console?

Answer (score 2):

Pentaho files are found at:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files

The server is in the 'Business Intelligence Server' folder.

Download the zip file of the latest version, and unzip it. Open a terminal at the location of the unziped directory, and then cd into the directory. Now run ./start-pentaho.sh. It is a java application, so make sure you have java installed.

The server is now running, and the 'user console' can be accessed through a web browser at localhost:8080 by default. It was very slow for me, just fyi. The default login is 'admin' and 'password'.

Comment: I'm not sure why I had a hard time with this, but I had to search each step out on google. I wanted to post my findings somewhere to help others that come along later, and I have always found stack overflow extremely helpful. I don't have enough reputation to ask on stack overflow meta whether this format is acceptable for stack overflow, so I will when I do.

Comment: This should probably also be migrated to the database administrators stack exchange. Apologies.