# How to install Pentaho Community Server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bigdata, pentaho, pentaho-cde

This question seems like an obvious one. But trust me I couldn't find a single correct documentation on how to install Pentaho Community Edition on Ubuntu environment. Some of the guides that I found was incomplete and out of date. Most importantly most of the guides were for Windows environment. Can someone give the correct guide for installation of Pentaho on Ubuntu Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to download PDI and unzip the folder and start using it.
The only thing pentaho demands is java, you must have java_home path defined,no extra configuration required.

Comment: I downloaded the Pentaho server from source forge website. After extracting the ZIP file content have files like following. What do I need to run?

Comment: You have to start server, so execute "start-pentaho.sh" file and your server will start(don't close the prompt) if java_home path is settted up.

Comment: there is no any file named as pentaho.sh it has a file as start-pentaho.sh I ran it in a terminal. Then how can I access Pentaho from the browser?

Comment: i have edited my previous comment, you have to execute "start-pentaho.sh" file.

Comment: yeah I ran that bash file. But how to access or login to pentaho from browser?

Comment: once the server starts you can access it using this URL : http://localhost:8080/pentaho

Comment: This response comes up in the browser.       This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: check this answer, you have to follow the same steps.
check whether you missed something 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425314/how-is-the-pentaho-community-server-installed-on-linux